# TypeError: _this2.props.someFunciton is not a function - react

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, react-props

Although there are posts with similar titles, they are all irrelevant or don't answer the question that was posted.

I have a component that is called like this inside another page:

```
<SomeComponent  aParticularProp={(arg) => {this.someFunction(arg)}} />
```

Here is a simplified version of what SomeComponent looks like:

```
 class SomeComponent extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {someState: "test"};
}

something(){
  return (
      <SpecialButton 
          onClick={() => {this.props.someFunction(this.state.someState)}}
      />
  )

}

render () {
   return (
         {this.something()}
   ); 
}

}
```

Why am I getting "TypeError: _this2.props.someFunciton is not a function" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to pass a function down from a parent to a child component and maintain the original context, it is worth binding it to that component by either:

`<SomeComponent someFunction={this.someFunction.bind(this)} />`

**OR** by declaring your function like so: `someFunction = args => {}`

More to your point of why `this2.props.someFunction is not a function`, by passing your function down like so `someFunction={(arg) => {this.someFunction(arg)}}` you aren't actually passing down the function to the child component, but rather invoking the function and returning the results.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing aParticularProp as a prop, not SomeFunction...
So, in SomeComponent you can refer to this.props.aParticularProp.

And this.someFunction in the parent component is supposed to be defined in the parent component.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not it because I just wrote my post code wrong. Will edit.

Comment: I take that back. After further inspecting it was because I recently changed the variable name in the code and didn't change the jest test variable names to reflect it. So I'll change it back to the way it was. So in a way you were right. No longer getting error.